# Prolog Sudoku with permutation

Tags: prolog, permutation, sudoku

Here's sudoku each X is a box in a 6x6 sudoku we're give the ones i try to set in the beginning. Thought this strategy would work but I guess not :I
"Set the known values of the X’s and then generate needed permutations and test for compliance with problem constraints."
need help! I don't know why this won't work!
Heres updated version, still no response true or false from prolog.Just chugs away without telling me what the solution is to the sudoku. It's also using 98% of my cpu while it's not responding so go figure. Can anyone help me?

```
sudoku(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,
X9,X10,X11,X12,X13,X14,X15,X16,X17,
X18,X19,X20,X21,X22,X23,X24,X25,X26,
X27,X28,X28,X30,X31,X32,X33,X34,X35,X36):-

 X2=4,
 X4=2,
 X7=3,
 X9=1,
 X13=6,
 X24=6,
 X30=2,
 X33=3,
 X34=6,
 X35=1,

 permutation([X1,X3,X5,X6],[1,3,5,6]),
 permutation([X8,X10,X11,X12],[2,4,5,6]),
 permutation([X14,X15,X16,X17,X18],[1,2,3,4,5]),
 permutation([X19,X20,X21,X22,X23],[1,2,3,4,5]),
 permutation([X25,X26,X27,X28,X29],[1,3,4,5,6]),
 permutation([X31,X32,X36],[2,4,5]),

 permutation([X1,X19,X25,X31],[1,2,4,5]),
 permutation([X8,X14,X20,X26,X32],[1,2,3,5,6]),
 permutation([X3,X15,X21,X27],[2,4,5,6]),
 permutation([X10,X16,X22,X28],[1,3,4,5]),
 permutation([X5,X11,X17,X23,X29],[2,3,4,5,6]),
 permutation([X6,X12,X18,X36],[1,3,4,5]),

 permutation([X1,X3,X8],[2,5,6]),
 permutation([X5,X6,X10,X11,X12],[1,3,4,5,6]),
 permutation([X14,X15,X19,X20,X21],[1,2,3,4,5]),
 permutation([X16,X17,X18,X22,X23],[1,2,3,4,5]),
 permutation([X25,X26,X27,X31,X32],[1,2,4,5,6]),
 permutation([X28,X29,X36],[3,4,5]).
```

Comment: `permutation([X1,X3,X4,X5,X6],[1,3,5,6]),` can never succeed. And what do you mean by `(:=)/2`?

Comment: Oh thanks! Yeah I fixed that I had to remove X4 as it's already been defined at the bottom. each x represents a box in the sudoku. wouldn't X2:=4 set x2 to 4 when the user queries as sudoku(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,X10,X11,X12,X13,X14,X15,X16,X17,X18,X19,X20,X21,X22,X23,X24,X25,X26,X27,X28,X29,X30,X31,X32,X33,X34,X35,X36). it doesn't return false now but just doesn't return anything. I want it to return the values for the other boxes that haven't yet been defined. and what do you mean (:=)/2 where did i write that @false?

Comment: it's not returning anything does that mean it's processing over minutes? My cpu usage says it's using 99% cpu lol.

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: ubuntu i'm on swi-prolog @false

Comment: There is no `:=` in SWI? Use rather `=` and set these goals *first*, prior to `permutation/2`

Comment: What is meant by "constrictions"?

Comment: Ok I did as you said but it's still doing the same thing where I get no true or false back. @false

Comment: "Set the known values of the X’s and then generate needed permutations and test for compliance with problem constraints."
were the instructions @Boris

Comment: How did you write that program after all?

Comment: I posted an updated version @false. Any advice on how to fix it? Why aren't i getting a response?

Comment: Just a small comment: Considering that `permutation(Ls0, Ls)` for a list `Ls0` of length `L` has `L!` solutions, let us roughly estimate how long your approach may take in the worst case. You have 18 more or less independent calls of `permutation/2` which have on average (rough estimate) lists of length 5 as their arguments. So, we expect there are at worst about `(5!)^18` potential solutions that must be considered. That's about **10^38**. If you then also consider how many billions of solutions per second you can generate, you have a rough estimate for how long this will take to finish.

Comment: I'm not sure how many solutions I'm generating... what's a better approach? @mat

Comment: Instead of searching exhaustively through the whole space of potential solutions, I suggest you use *constraints* to express the relations between different variables, so that subconfigurations that cannot be extended to solutions are skipped as soon as possible. Check out `dif/2` for example, or finite domain constraints.

Comment: I'm new to prolog how do I implement that. I checked out dif/2 wouldn't it just be comparing 2 numbers? don't I need to compare more at a time? @mat

Comment: Sure, so you would use for example several `dif/2` goals to express this. `dif/2` is one of the most elementary constraints, like `=/2`. In this concrete case, since you are reasoning about integers, I recommend finite domain constraints, where constraints like `all_different/1` are already available.

Comment: I'm still not following can you write a line of sample code? @mat

Comment: Check out the [sample code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.prolog/2DXsy7QZZnQ/a6G7_wUfolsJ) for solving Sudoku with SICStus Prolog!

Comment: That's totally useless for this assignment. Can anyone help me out?!

Answer (score -1):

So I figured it out. The issue was that it was simply too large a task for a PC to do using purely permutations (although that is what the assignment called for). The solution is to rearrange the permutations in a more desireable fashion. As it is above, it computes rows, columns, then boxes, it's exponentially better to mix them to complete the task with more ease. as such:

```
sudoku(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,
X9,X10,X11,X12,X13,X14,X15,X16,X17,
X18,X19,X20,X21,X22,X23,X24,X25,X26,
X27,X28,X28,X30,X31,X32,X33,X34,X35,X36):-

 X2=4,
 X4=2,
 X7=3,
 X9=1,
 X13=6,
 X24=6,
 X30=2,
 X33=3,
 X34=6,
 X35=1,
%row
 permutation([X1,X3,X5,X6],[1,3,5,6]),
 permutation([X8,X10,X11,X12],[2,4,5,6]),
 %column
 permutation([X1,X19,X25,X31],[1,2,4,5]),
 permutation([X8,X14,X20,X26,X32],[1,2,3,5,6]),
 %box
 permutation([X1,X3,X8],[2,5,6]),
 permutation([X5,X6,X10,X11,X12],[1,3,4,5,6]),
 %row
 permutation([X14,X15,X16,X17,X18],[1,2,3,4,5]),
 permutation([X19,X20,X21,X22,X23],[1,2,3,4,5]),
 %column
 permutation([X3,X15,X21,X27],[2,4,5,6]),
 permutation([X10,X16,X22,X28],[1,3,4,5]),   
 %box
 permutation([X25,X26,X27,X28,X29],[1,3,4,5,6]),
 permutation([X31,X32,X36],[2,4,5]),
%row
 permutation([X14,X15,X19,X20,X21],[1,2,3,4,5]),
 permutation([X16,X17,X18,X22,X23],[1,2,3,4,5]), 
 %column
 permutation([X5,X11,X17,X23,X29],[2,3,4,5,6]),
 permutation([X6,X12,X18,X36],[1,3,4,5]),
 %box
 permutation([X25,X26,X27,X31,X32],[1,2,4,5,6]),
 permutation([X28,X29,X36],[3,4,5]).
```

The output is a little strange but correct. Once again Stackoverflow fails me and I have to answer my own question. Thanks for the downvote you geniuses.